# List questions that I've asked, that others have favorited, featured in my profile

Tags: feature-request, questions

Having questions that *I've* asked, that *others* have favorited, displayed in my profile, would be a very nice thing to show off.

Specifically, I'm suggesting a new tab called "Favorited" under "Questions" in the user profile, which would *feature* the questions I've asked that have been favorited.

[image]

I do understand that you can see the number of favorites among all your questions in other categories. I'm suggesting that it be a more prominent and filtered feature.

Thanks for considering!

This is a follow-up to a question I asked earlier today: *[What does marking a question as favorite (clicking the star) do?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6469/what-does-marking-a-question-as-favorite-clicking-the-star-do)*

Answer (score 5):

You should already have this.  Go take a look at [your questions tab](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/115641/aliteralmind?tab=questions).
8 people have put a star on your Bloch pattern question.

[image]

You could also use this [data explorer query](https://data.stackexchange.com/programmers/query/151567/who-favorited-my-questions) but keep in mind that the data is updated once a week or so.  So it won't reflect real time changes.
<sub>Hat tip to [MichaelT](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/users/40980/michaelt) for the query.</sub>

Comment: yes, but there's no way to “sort by favourites” inside the question list :(

Comment: @amon - use the DE query then.  :-)

Comment: I'm suggesting that my "favorited" questions be more prominently featured and *ordered by* the number of favorites, not just having the number of favorites listed among all questions under each existing category, which is what happens currently. I've updated my question to clarify this.